# Docker with Ubuntu 20.10: `strconv.Atoi: parsing "0-beta1": invalid syntax`

Tags: linux, ubuntu, docker

I just update all packages installed in my machine by using the usual:

```sh
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y && sudo apt autoremove -y
```

After rebooting the system I saw my Docker containers disappear from execution, then I decided to start the usual `hello-world` container. I retrieved the following error message.

```
sudouser@machine:~$ sudo docker run hello-world
docker: Error response from daemon: AppArmor enabled on system but the docker-default profile could not be loaded: strconv.Atoi: parsing "0-beta1": invalid syntax.
ERRO[0004] error waiting for container: context canceled
```

### Tried solutions

- Uninstall and reinstall Docker: *no changes*.

#### Useful information

```
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu Groovy Gorilla (development branch)
Release:    20.10
Codename:   groovy
Kernel:     GNU/Linux 5.8.0-19-generic x86_64
```

Answer (score 6):

hello I solved the problem by adding manually the docker file in /etc/apparmor.d directory:

```
$ /etc/apparmor.d$ cat docker 
#include <tunables/global>
profile docker-default flags=(attach_disconnected,mediate_deleted) {
  #include <abstractions/base>
  network,
  capability,
  file,
  umount,
  deny @{PROC}/* w,   # deny write for all files directly in /proc (not in a subdir)
  # deny write to files not in /proc/<number>/** or /proc/sys/**
  deny @{PROC}/{[^1-9],[^1-9][^0-9],[^1-9s][^0-9y][^0-9s],[^1-9][^0-9][^0-9][^0-9]*}/** w,
  deny @{PROC}/sys/[^k]** w,  # deny /proc/sys except /proc/sys/k* (effectively /proc/sys/kernel)
  deny @{PROC}/sys/kernel/{?,??,[^s][^h][^m]**} w,  # deny everything except shm* in /proc/sys/kernel/
  deny @{PROC}/sysrq-trigger rwklx,
  deny @{PROC}/mem rwklx,
  deny @{PROC}/kmem rwklx,
  deny @{PROC}/kcore rwklx,
  deny mount,
  deny /sys/[^f]*/** wklx,
  deny /sys/f[^s]*/** wklx,
  deny /sys/fs/[^c]*/** wklx,
  deny /sys/fs/c[^g]*/** wklx,
  deny /sys/fs/cg[^r]*/** wklx,
  deny /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/** rwklx,
  deny /sys/kernel/security/** rwklx,
  # suppress ptrace denials when using 'docker ps' or using 'ps' inside a container ptrace (trace,read) peer=docker-default,
}

$ /etc/init.d/apparmor restart
$ docker run hello-world
Hello from Docker!
This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly.
To generate this message, Docker took the following steps:
 1. The Docker client contacted the Docker daemon.
 2. The Docker daemon pulled the "hello-world" image from the Docker Hub.
    (amd64)
 3. The Docker daemon created a new container from that image which runs the
    executable that produces the output you are currently reading.
 4. The Docker daemon streamed that output to the Docker client, which sent it
    to your terminal.
To try something more ambitious, you can run an Ubuntu container with:
 $ docker run -it ubuntu bash
Share images, automate workflows, and more with a free Docker ID:
 https://hub.docker.com/
For more examples and ideas, visit:
 https://docs.docker.com/get-started/
```

Comment: I had to create the `docker` file and made the mistake of initially putting it `/etc/apparmor` instead of `/etc/apparmor.d` but once I fixed that, this solution worked like a dream! Thanks @roma59

Comment: I confirm adding the docker file to /etc/apparmor.d and restart apparmor fixed the error. I have no idea why it worked. Thank you for the solution.

Answer (score 2):

I saw this too after an upgrade from 20.04.

Here are the steps I took and I was able to get Docker running again.

```
sudo apt install docker.io

# Unmask docker, otherwise cannot start docker because "docker.service is masked"
sudo systemctl unmask docker

sudo service docker start
```

Then I was able to run docker commands

Comment: Thanks @PatViafore! Your solution seems to work! I will test it in the following days and I will get back at you for the "Accepted answer".

Comment: Failed to start docker.service: Unit docker.service is masked.

Answer (score 0):

@PatViafore answer is correct if you don't want to run **docker-ce**

If you want to run docker-ce package, you must edit your sources.list file and add/edit a line as follows:

```
deb https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal stable edge test
```

After upgrade **docker-ce** package, you must run docker now:

```
$ docker run hello-world

Hello from Docker!
This message shows that your installation appears to be working correctly.

To generate this message, Docker took the following steps:
 1. The Docker client contacted the Docker daemon.
 2. The Docker daemon pulled the "hello-world" image from the Docker Hub.
    (amd64)
 3. The Docker daemon created a new container from that image which runs the
    executable that produces the output you are currently reading.
 4. The Docker daemon streamed that output to the Docker client, which sent it
    to your terminal.

To try something more ambitious, you can run an Ubuntu container with:
 $ docker run -it ubuntu bash

Share images, automate workflows, and more with a free Docker ID:
 https://hub.docker.com/

For more examples and ideas, visit:
 https://docs.docker.com/get-started/
```

Tested in my groovy laptop:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu Groovy Gorilla (development branch)
Release:    20.10
Codename:   groovy
$ docker --version
Docker version 19.03.13, build 4484c46d9d
```

Comment: Unfortunately, didn't remove the error for me (exact same Ubuntu and Docker version). Doesn't seem to differentiate between `stable`, `test` and `nightly`. Anyways, switching to **docker.io** is a valid option:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45023363/what-is-docker-io-in-relation-to-docker-ce-and-docker-ee

Comment: Thanks for your comment @cubells! Unfortunately this does not solved the problem as pointed out by @User Rebo. Have you any other suggestion?